# Im practicing using Linked Lists and nodes in C and I keep getting "Unhandled Exceptions" at runtime

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, nodes, unhandled-exception

What am I doing wrong? I've managed to remove all the errors but I'm still not sure why I cant at least add a node as it looks right? also what am I meant to do with listPtr? Ino it should be there as the question im trying to answer asks to initialize a second node but Im not sure if its ment to somehow be used in addToStart?

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>



        struct node
        {
         int data;
         struct node *next;
        };

        void addToStart(struct node **head);
        void printList();
        void addToEnd(struct node* head);


        int main(){

            int choice = 0;

            struct node *head = (struct node *)malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
            struct node *listPtr;

            head->data= 42;
            head->next = NULL;

            listPtr = head;

            printf("Pick one of the following:\n");
            printf("1) add node to start\n");
            printf("2) add node to end\n");
            printf("3) display all nodes\n");
            printf("4) display length\n");
            printf("5) search list\n");

            scanf("%d", choice);

            switch(choice){
            case 1:
                addToStart(&head);
                break;
            case 2:
                addToEnd(head);
                break;
            case 3:
                printList();
                break;
            }
        }


        void addToStart (struct node **head)
        {
        struct node *newNode;
        newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("\nEnter data for this node");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->data);
        newNode->next = *head;
        *head = newNode; // transfer the address of newNode' to 'head'
        }

        void addToEnd(struct node* head)
        {
        struct node *endNode;
        struct node *temp;
        temp =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp = head;
        while(temp->next != NULL) // go to the last node
        {
        temp = temp->next;
        }
        endNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("\nEnter data for this node");
        scanf("%d", &endNode->data);
        endNode->next = NULL;
        temp->next = endNode ;
        }


        void printList(struct node *head){

            struct node *temp; 
            temp = head;  
            if(head == NULL){
                printf("Empty list");
            }
            else{
                while(temp != NULL){

                    printf("Data: %d", temp->data); // show the data
                    temp = temp->next; 
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any loop in main, so your program can only ever add one item to the list before it exits (without printing anything).  You need to have a loop so you can select more than one menu choice per run.

Note that if you run the program over again, the list will be cleared to empty.  So you can't expect to run the program a second time and print the list from the first run.

Oh by the way I spotted a bug: `scanf("%d", &choice);`  You need the `&` there.